# Angular 1 lendo JSON cross-domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html5, json

Galera to tendo um pequeno problema com angular e queria saber se alguém consegue me ajuda, me pediram a seguinte tarefa fazer uma prateleira a partir de produtos de um JSON externo (onde tem toda a info de cada produto).

```js
const API_URL = '/caminho/para/JSON.json';
var app = angular.module('root', []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $http({
  method: 'JSONP',
    url: API_URL
  }).then(function (success){
    $scope.content = "Something went right";
   },function (error){
    $scope.content = "Something went wrong";
   });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-app="root">
  <h1 ng-controller="testCtrl">
    {{content}}
  </h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

<--TRECHO DO JSON-->

```
[
  {
    "productId": "2000646",
    "productName": "Fitnow T-Shirt loja-teste - Feminino",
    "brand": "loja-teste",
    "categoriesIds": [
        "/104/72/",
        "/104/",
        "/104/267/"
    ],
    "gender": [
        "female"
    ],
    "age_group": [
        "adult"
    ],
    "Atributos Google": [
        "gender",
        "age_group"
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "itemId": "24121",
            "name": "| PRETO - P",
            "nameComplete": "Fitnow T-Shirt loja-teste - Feminino | PRETO - P",
            "ean": "78993232323",
            "referenceId": [
                {
                    "Key": "RefId"
                }
            ],
            "Cor": [
                "Preto e Verde"
            ],
            "Tamanho": [
                "P"
            ],
            "variations": [
                "Cor",
                "Tamanho"
            ],
        },
    ]
  },
]
```

Não consigo fazer com que ele leia nenhum dado desse JSON, nem ao menos ele aparenta carregar pois quando roda ele aparece somente que deu algo de errado pelo meu scope.Esse é outro problema que estou tendo não estou conseguindo saber muito bem como referenciar as linhas desse JSON o que está me complicando bastante.

Alguém tem alguma luz para esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa enviar cabeçalhos no seu serviço `$http`:

```
$http({
    method: 'JSONP',
    url: API_URL,
    headers: {
        Content-Type: "application/json"
        // Você pode precisar da autorização também
        //Authorization: token  
    }
}).then(function ( success ){
    $scope.content = "Something went right";
},function ( error ){
    $scope.content = "Something went wrong";
});
```

Certifique-se de que o servidor ao qual você faz requisições tem [**CORS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS) configurado (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, e.g.).